# Geographic background containing both outlines and contours: how?

Tags: geography

I would like to create a map which will show lakes and rivers together with elevation contours and contour labels.  What is the simplest way to do this with `GeoGraphics` in version 10?

The solution I have (below) looks much too convoluted.

---

I need to plot this point on the map:

```
pos = WeatherData["KP60", "Coordinates"]
```

This is good, except the background is not what I need:

```
g = GeoGraphics[{PointSize[Large], Darker@Red, Point[pos]}]
```

[image]

Since I can't seem to mix two `GeoStyle`s, I tried overlaying a polygon that contains the contours.  This lead to the following:

```
{range, projection} = {GeoRange, GeoProjection} /. Options[g, {GeoRange, GeoProjection}]

{a, b, d, c} = Tuples[Reverse@range]

GeoGraphics[{{GeoStyling["ContourMap", ContourShading -> None,  ContourLabels -> True], Polygon[{a, b, c, d}]}, {PointSize@Large, Darker@Red, Point[pos]}}, GeoRange -> range]
```

[image]

However, now the projection has changed, and adding `GeoProjection -> projection` causes the polygon not to show.  Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to mixing geopositions and raw long/lat pairs.  `pos` is expressed as a `GeoPosition` and the polygon is expressed as raw pairs.  The graphics are better behaved if all coordinates are expessed in the same fashion.

**Option one: use geopositions throughout**

Change the assignment to `{a, b, d, c}` from this:

```
{a, b, d, c} = Tuples[Reverse@range]
(* {{-110.652, 44.3787}, {-110.652, 44.7093}, {-110.19, 44.3787}, {-110.19, 44.7093}} *)
```

to this:

```
{a, d, b, c} = GeoPosition /@ Tuples[range]
(* {GeoPosition[{44.3787, -110.652}], GeoPosition[{44.3787, -110.19}], 
    GeoPosition[{44.7093, -110.652}], GeoPosition[{44.7093, -110.19}]}*)
```

**Option two: use raw long/lat pairs throughout**

Change the assignment to `pos` from this:

```
pos = WeatherData["KP60", "Coordinates"]
(* GeoPosition[{44.544, -110.421}] *)
```

to this:

```
pos = Reverse @ First @ WeatherData["KP60", "Coordinates"]
(* {-110.421, 44.544} *)
```

**Why do mixed coordinates behave like this?**

I don't know, that remains to be seen... :)

Interestingly, if the `Point` uses a raw pair and `Polygon` uses geopositions (option 3: the reverse situation from the original code), then the result is well-behaved.  Perhaps there is a bug in `Polygon`?

If we are using the mixed coordinates from the original code, the following expression suggests that there is some kind of projection mismatch:

```
GeoGraphics[
  { { GeoStyling["ContourMap", ContourShading -> None,  ContourLabels -> True]
    , Polygon[{a, b, c, d}]
    }
  , {PointSize@Large, Orange, Point[pos]}
  }
, GeoProjection -> projection
]
```

[image: geographics screenshot]

The `GeoRange` option has been deleted so that we can see the entire range.  The `GeoProjection` option has been added.  Note how the contoured polygon is being plotted in a different location despite having overlapping coordinates.  Is the wrong projection being used?